# Table responsible for Recid generation?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Hi can anyone please tell me 
1. which is the table responsible for rec id generation 
2. Can any 2 table have the same recid in ax 2009 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SystemSequences` table stores RecId information for each table. In AX 2009 RecIds are unique per table, so two different tables could have records with the same recid.

Comment: This therefore means we don't need to additionally join by company (DataAreaId) between tables when already using the RecId/RefRecId fields...